# Can I choose which listener to run if two components listen to the same database reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have two components A and B. When A is rendered, it listens to and child_added event for messagesRef in firebase realtime database.

```
  state = {
    messagesRef: firebase.database().ref("privateMessages")
  };

addListeners = currentUserUid => {
    this.state.messagesRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    ...
    }
}
```

However component B will be rendered from A, and it also has the same listener to the same reference. In this case, how can I choose to only make B's listener as an active, and disable A's listener? For now, I had a workaround in B by explicitly calling `.off()` for all A's listener, and then call `.on()`. Code snipeet is like below. It somewhat solved my problem. But I don't know if it is legit, if not, if there is any better way. Thanks!

```
addListeners = currentUserUid => {
    // explicitly .off all existing ones
    this.state.messagesRef.off();
    this.state.channels.forEach(channel => {
      this.state.messagesRef.child(channel.id).off();
    });

    // then do .on() again
    this.state.messagesRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing seems OK to me.  There might not be any real harm in leaving the listener active, since two listeners at the same location will not double the amount of bandwidth used if there was just a single listener.  The listeners will effectively share the snapshot data.

Comment: Thanks for your input Doug! I appreciate it!